# How to change default post type / post to media or attachments

Tags: query-posts

Im using wordpress 3.1.1, in frontpage i need to display only the media uploads, now im using this acction:

```
add_action( 'parse_query', 'custom_query' );

function custom_query( &$query ) {

  $query->set( 'post_type', array('attachment') );

}
```

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( &$query ) {

```
  if ( is_home() || is_frontpage() ) {

    $query->set( 'post_status', 'inherit' );
    $query->set( 'post_type', 'attachment' );

  }


  return $query;

}
```

But doesnt work.

Any help is working.

Comment: change `media` to `attachment`

Comment: I did it but doesnt work. Above I pasted the code im using.

Comment: Nope, sorry, now is working with the add_filter. Thank you Bainternet

Comment: @Bainternet: Can you move that comment to an answer?

Comment: @Jan: can, and done. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it right, it should be `attachment` instead of `media` since all media uploads are "called" attachments" in WordPress,
so:

```
 $query->set( 'post_type', 'attachment' );
```